# Lockbind variables by default

Tags: r

I made some research for lockbinding variables and have found the following options (see below). Anyone knows of an approach where I can lock the variables by default? And with a simple expression like (<-%) I can bypass the locking?

```
# option 1
library(pryr)
xvar %<c-% 10
xvar
xvar <- 11


# option 2
remove(list = ls())
xvar <- 10
xvar
## [1] 2
lockBinding('xvar', .GlobalEnv)
xvar <- 11

# my preferred option
remove(list = ls())
xvar <- 10
xvar <- 11
# "Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'xvar'"
xvar <-% 11
xvar
#11
```

Comment: is \`<-\` <- pryr::\`%<c-%\` enough ? what do you want do to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you can override any function, even those of base R.

Hence, inside the console :

```
library(pryr)
`<-` <- pryr::`%<c-%`
```

will do the trick, with an overriding in the global env.

If you want to put it outside of the global env, then making a package exporting `<-` could do the trick. So make a new package and put that in the code :

```
`<-` <- function (x, value)
{
  assign("name",substitute(x))
  if (!is.name(name))
    stop("Left-hand side must be a name")
  assign("env",parent.frame())
  assign(as.character(name), value, env)
  lockBinding(name, env)
  invisible(value)
}
```

(it's pryr one modified with assign)

and write

```
export(`<-`)
```

inside its namespace.

If you want to do things automatically, the **RProfile.site** file inside *R\R-4.0.2\etc* is a script you load at the start of each R session. So you can write there `library(thenameyouhavechosenforyourpackage)`.

In your R session, detaching the package will end this behaviour.

Comment: hmm, but I have just realized that it is actually pretty dangerous since:  y %<c-% 1 + 2 and z %<c-% (1 + 2) is not the same. need to find another solution then. thank you anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044891/in-r-how-can-i-determine-the-operator-precedence-of-user-defined-infix-operator it seems that you can't define operator precedences if you're dealing with user-defined operators. I'll search through.

Comment: I've tested my solution, overrwriting `<-` and it keeps the operator precedence of `<-`